# I'm Unable to set value of textbox using php variable

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to set value of html input type text textboxes to empty when user clicks Search button and empID is not matched, but its giving error:

mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result

Here is code:

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
<h2>Employee Form</h2>

<input type="text" name="empID">
<input type="submit" name="searchRec" value="Search" />
<hr>

  Employee ID: <input type="text" name="empIDC" value="<?php echo htmlentities($employeeID); ?>">
  <br><br>

  Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo htmlentities($Name); ?>">
  <br><br>

  Address: <input type="text" name="address" value="<?php echo htmlentities($Address); ?>">
  <br><br>
</form>
<?php
if( isset( $_REQUEST['searchRec'] ))
{
$employeeID = ($_POST["empID"]);

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "bc140_DB";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$sql = "SELECT empID, Name, Address, Dateofbirth, Salary, Timein from Employee where empID == $employeeID";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result > 0)){   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {   $employeeID = $row['empID'];   $Name = $row['Name'];   $Address = $row['Address'];   $Dateofbirth = $row['Dateofbirth'];   $Salary = $row['Salary'];   $timestamp = $row['timeIn']; } }else{     $employeeID = "";   $Name = ""; $Address = "";   $Dateofbirth = "";   $Salary = "";   $timestamp = ""; }

}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: sure you will get undefined variable error .

Comment: Suggestion: use `isset()` in your inputs values to check and make sure the value is set before declaring it be placed there in the input; `value="<?php if(isset($_POST['address'])) { echo htmlentities($Address); }else{ echo ""; } ?>"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1st :** Change your `code order` otherwise you will get `undefined` error  . your trying the embed the variable with html before creating the variable .

**2nd :**  should be use single `=`  not `==`  `empID = $employeeID`

**3rd :** your mixing `mysql` with `mysqli` here  `mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)`

Change to

```
mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

**4th:** And also use `isset()` to confirm that variable exists or not if exists echo it otherwise echo the empty string .

**5th:** change your if like this `if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){ }`

file.php

```
<?php
if( isset( $_REQUEST['searchRec'] ))
{
   ......
  $employeeID = $row['empID'];
  $Name = $row['Name'];
  $Address = $row['Address'];
  $Dateofbirth = $row['Dateofbirth'];
  $Salary = $row['Salary'];
  $timestamp = $row['timeIn'];
   ......
}
?>

<html>
<body>
.....
  Employee ID: <input type="text" name="empIDC" value="<?php  if(isset($employeeID)){ echo htmlentities($employeeID); } else { echo ""; }  ?>">
.....

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I changed the order by making php code before <html> but errors are still there.

Comment: I changed code order, used = to match empID, and used mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);  but errors are still there

Comment: can you update your new  code in post . @Jazib_Prince

Comment: Thanks JYoThl by follwoing all steps you mentioned+using isset solved the issue.
Now I'm trying to do this:
if(mysqli_num_rows($result > 0)){
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
  $employeeID = $row['empID'];
  $Name = $row['Name'];
  $Address = $row['Address'];
  $Dateofbirth = $row['Dateofbirth'];
  $Salary = $row['Salary'];
  $timestamp = $row['timeIn'];
}
}else{
 $employeeID = "";
  $Name = "";
  $Address = "";
  $Dateofbirth = "";
  $Salary = "";
  $timestamp = "";
}its not working error: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result

Comment: Please dont' push the code in comment box . it's too hard to read . try to edit your post using edit button @Jazib_Prince

Comment: change your if like this if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){  }

Comment: @JYoThl I edited the post and if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0) this didn't worked

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148678/discussion-between-jazib-prince-and-jyothi).

Comment: still your code not updated  fully . here empID == $employeeID . please update entire code . @Jazib_Prince

Answer (score 1):

you have forgotten `';'`   `value="<?php echo htmlentities($employeeID); ?>"`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out mistake, but errors are still there after inserting ; at the end of all statements.

Comment: @Jazib_Prince and change the order like JYoThI said.

Comment: @Jazib_Prince try change ur query SELECT * FROM Employee where empID == $employeeID"  and try to echo the variables after foreach loop to see if u are getting them

Comment: var_dump() your query to see if it gets results. Check the query stmt in SQL and see if passes an SQL entry in phpMyAdmin if available.